# Cannot install react-navigation and gestures

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

got this error while installing

```
npm install react-navigation
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\subba-workstation\Desktop\practise\ecommerceApp\node_modules\fsevents' -> 'C:\Users\subba-workstation\Desktop\practise\ecommerceApp\node_modules\.fsevents.DELETE'

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! path C:\Users\subba-workstation\Desktop\practise\ecommerceApp\node_modules\hoist-non-react-statics
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\subba-workstation\Desktop\practise\ecommerceApp\node_modules\.hoist-non-react-statics.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\subba-workstation\Desktop\practise\ecommerceApp\node_modules\hoist-non-react-statics' -> 'C:\Users\subba-workstation\Desktop\practise\ecommerceApp\node_modules\.hoist-non-react-statics.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\subba-workstation\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-14T13_22_46_720Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try to install them using the Yarn command in the project console:

```
yarn add @react-navigation/native
```

Comment: For further information please read the [React Navigation's Documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/)

Comment: i'm new to this platform and haven't use yarn and am afraid that npm and yarn might crash
i want to solve with npm instead

Comment: Try using npm doctor to check if there's a missing dependencies and by then you could fix them easily

Comment: sorry for the trouble. The problem was due to react-navigation version 4 and 5, I was following the tutorial that used version 4 and the documentation was on version 5.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to solve the issue.

1. `npm cache clean -f`
2. `remove node_module folder manually`
3. `npm i`

Comment: Judging by the path, it's a Windows system though.

Comment: I tried this but it caused more errors. 
sorry not doing this again.